# Where the uploadfile_ptr comes from when I use inherit to create the model?

Tags: python, django

I change my upload file model `WorkOrderUploadFile` to inherit from base model like bellow:

Base model:

```
def generate_files_directory(instance, filename):

    url = "%s/%s" % (instance.filepath , filename) # will output something like `images/imgs/test/`
    return url


class UploadFile(models.Model):
    """
    Base upload model
    """
    #filepath = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="images/qiyun_admin_servicemanage_workorder/")

    file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_files_directory)
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file
```

My `WorkOrderUploadFile` class:

```
class WorkOrderUploadFile(UploadFile):
    """
    work order upload file
    """
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="images/qiyun_admin_servicemanage_workorder/")
```

When I makemigrations, I get bellow issue:

```
$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'uploadfile_ptr' to workorderuploadfile without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

But I did not add a field name `uploadfile_ptr` in my base model and how to deal with it? I tried give `1` to the value but I still get error, it will report error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

---

**EDIT**

The base model and the subclass model do not in a same project.

---

**EDIT-2**

I add the default value to in my base model.

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_files_directory, default="")
```

But still has this issue.

---

**EDIT-3**

I tried add the Meta to the base model still do not work:

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to add default value for `models.FileField`.

This is usually because there are some existing rows in your original database which doesn't contains `file`. So when you `makemigrations`, db server cannot decide the value of this additional column.